# How to sort array of objects based on a boolean property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have list of users presented in table. **Active users should be sorted above the inactive users.**

I am trying to make this `sort` using lodash `sortBy` function, but unsuccessfully.

Here is how `userArray` looks:

```
const userArray [
  { 
    // I need to show users which have disabled = false first 
    // and then users with disabled = true
    disabled: true,  // <==========
    email: "hgaither@cmregent.com",
    firstName: "Harriet",
    lastName: "Gaither",
    role: "claimsHandlerSupervisor",
    userId: "03VFpxtMWgY1jKDHDLcrWSw1qzx1",
  }, 
  {
   disabled: false,  // <===========
   email: "hgaither@cmregent.com",
   firstName: "Harriet",
   lastName: "Gaither",
   role: "claimsHandlerSupervisor",
   userId: "03VFpxtMWgY1jKDHDLcrWSw1qzx1",
 }, 
]
```

here is code pen with code with users array and sortBy loadsh function:
https://codepen.io/nikolatrajkovicq/pen/pGXdpM?editors=1112

Any adivce is welcome.

Comment: you could just create 2 arrays with enabled and disabled users, than concat the disabled on the end of enabled, this will make disabled users to appear in the end (but not sorted in any order order)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) like this:

```js
const userArray=[{disabled:true,email:"hgaither@cmregent.com",firstName:"Harriet",lastName:"Gaither",role:"claimsHandlerSupervisor",userId:"03VFpxtMWgY1jKDHDLcrWSw1qzx1",},{disabled:false,email:"hgaither@cmregent.com",firstName:"Harriet",lastName:"Gaither",role:"claimsHandlerSupervisor",userId:"03VFpxtMWgY1jKDHDLcrWSw1qzx1",},]

userArray.sort((a,b) => a.disabled - b.disabled)
console.log(userArray)
```

You can just subtract the boolean property inside the `compareFunction`. This works because of coercion

```
true - false === 1
false - true === -1
true - true === 0
```

Comment: thank you for solution and help!
I still didn't understood how this works, if you can give me some more inforimation?

Comment: @JamesDelaney please go through the `sort` link in the answer. It explains the `compareFunction` function in detail. The compare function sorts 2 items realtive to each other based on whether the return value is +ve, -ve or 0. Since `false - true` returns `-1` and vice versa, we can simply subtract the `disabled` properties of 2 items being compared

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**sort**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
const userArray = [{disabled:true,email:"hgaither@cmregent.com",firstName:"Harriet",lastName:"Gaither",role:"claimsHandlerSupervisor",userId:"03VFpxtMWgY1jKDHDLcrWSw1qzx1",},{disabled:false,email:"hgaither@cmregent.com",firstName:"Harriet",lastName:"Gaither",role:"claimsHandlerSupervisor",userId:"03VFpxtMWgY1jKDHDLcrWSw1qzx1",},{disabled:true,email:"hgither@cmregent.com",firstName:"Hrriet",lastName:"Gither",role:"claisHandlerSupervisor",userId:"0VFpxtMWgY1jKDHDLcrWSw1qzx1",},]

let op = userArray.sort(({disabled:A}, {disabled:B})=> A-B)

console.log(op)
```

Comment: this doesn't work. The result shows `true -> false -> true`

Comment: OP said _I need to show first users which have disabled property False then users which true_. Your code shows the user with `true` first

Comment: `First should be presented Active useres and on the End Inactive users` @MaheerAli

Comment: @adiga did you checked the snippet output really ?

Comment: @Code Maniac `disabled:true` means inactive I guess

Comment: [Sorting in JavaScript: Shouldn't returning a boolean be enough for a comparison function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785)

Comment: @adiga i am using on firefox and it seems to give fine result for me. didn't knew that this is dependent implementations

Answer (score 0):

```
userArray.sort((a, b) => {
  // Sort objects with disabled: false first
  if (a.disabled === false && b.disabled === true) {
    return -1; // a comes before b
  } 
  // Sort objects with disabled: true after objects with disabled: false
  else if (a.disabled === true && b.disabled === false) {
    return 1; // b comes before a
  } 
  // Keep the order unchanged if both objects have the same disabled value
  else {
    return 0;
  }
});

console.log(userArray);
```