# Algorithm to sort Map and reasign new order on value change

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I am developing an E-Commerce using Javascript. In the section of the products of the page, I want to implement the functionality to change the order of the products setting the number in the corresponding input. You can see an image to get an idea of the interface.

[image]

The algorithm I looking for has to reorder all the products if the user changes the input of the **Orden column**.

For example:

1. The user sets the input Orden of the product 0003-0020 to 11 and clicks on the **Guardar** button.
2. Then, the algorithm has to change the position of this product and put it second on the list. Updating its **orden input value** to 20.
3. The algorithm has to update all the following products, increasing their positions +10.

*If the user sets a value that already exists, the product will place below the product that already has the position entered.*
*The position values are always multiple of 10.*

The data is structured in an ArrayList that contains the product reference and its position:
Its name is **lista_variantes**.

```
0: {numero: "0003-0007", posicion: 10}
1: {numero: "0003-0006", posicion: 20}
2: {numero: "0003-0004", posicion: 30}
3: {numero: "0003-0008", posicion: 40}
4: {numero: "0003-0014", posicion: 50}
5: {numero: "0003-0016", posicion: 60}
6: {numero: "0003-0017", posicion: 70}
7: {numero: "0003-0018", posicion: 80}
```

And then using this map, I update the Database and read the product information in the correct order. I have implemented correctly this, I only want the algorithm to achieve the example behaviour.

Comment: When you click on save, `map` is already updated with `11` value for that object? Is `map` an array of objects? The current structure is not valid JavaScript syntax

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You could `map` the array of objects and add a new property called `isUpdated` which checks if the `posicion` is same based on the index.
- Then, `sort` the array based on `posicion`. If 2 items have the same `posicion`, then sort them based on `isUpdated` property
- Then `map` the array again to remove the `isUpdated` property and get the `posicion` values based on their index

```js
const map = [
    { numero: "0003-0007", posicion: 10 },
    { numero: "0003-0006", posicion: 20 },
    { numero: "0003-0004", posicion: 30 },
    { numero: "0003-0008", posicion: 25 }, //-- updated
    { numero: "0003-0014", posicion: 20 }, //-- updated
    { numero: "0003-0016", posicion: 60 }
]

const output = map.map((o, i) => ({ ...o, isUpdated: (i+1) * 10 !== o.posicion }))
                  .sort((a,b) => a.posicion - b.posicion || a.isUpdated - b.isUpdated)
                  .map(({ isUpdated, ...rest }, i) => ({ ...rest, posicion: (i+1) * 10 }))

console.log(output)
```

It would be better if you have another property to keep the `posicion` value before update or an onchange event which updates the `isUpdated` proeprty. If you have that, you can skip the step where you check whether the object has been updated or not.

Here's a snippet using for loop and some comments

```js
const map = [
    { numero: "0003-0007", posicion: 10 },
    { numero: "0003-0006", posicion: 20 },
    { numero: "0003-0004", posicion: 30 },
    { numero: "0003-0008", posicion: 25 }, //-- updated
    { numero: "0003-0014", posicion: 20 }, //-- updated
    { numero: "0003-0016", posicion: 60 }
]

// add isUpdated property and set it to true if posicion is not equal to (i+1) * 10
for (let i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
  const o = map[i];
  o.isUpdated = (i+1) * 10 !== o.posicion
}

// sort based on posicion
// if both have the same posicion, the subtraction returns 0
// so, || will check the next condition
// Sorting based on boolean: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54826593
map.sort((a,b) => a.posicion - b.posicion || a.isUpdated - b.isUpdated);

// delete the isUpdated property
// update the posicion based on the new index
for (let i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
  const o = map[i];
  o.posicion = (i+1) * 10;
  delete o.isUpdated
}

console.log(map)
```

Comment: How would you do it to add the isUpdated boolean?

Comment: I didn't understand your question

Comment: What you said at the end of your answare.

Comment: If you are using some 2-way binding framework, you could have 2 separate properties for `posicion` both have the same value when this component loads and one of them bound to that input data and changes when the user types there. Then isUpdated can be computed with `initialPosicion !== o.inputPosicion`. Or, an `onChange` event on the input. When the value changes check if the value entered is different than `initialPosicion` value or it's different than `(i+1) * 10`, set `isUpdated = true`

Comment: Please, can you explain the code of the output map?

Comment: I have tried what you say, but I don't understand really well what your code does...   
`const newOrder = list.map((o, i) => ({ ...o, isUpdated: (i+1) * 10 !== o.initialPosition }))
                  .sort((a,b) => a.position - b.position || a.isUpdated - b.isUpdated)
                  .map(({ isUpdated, ...rest }, i) => ({ ...rest, initialPosition, position: (i+1) * 10 }));
        return newOrder;`

Comment: @EmiliBellotPulido The last `map` uses rest syntax in [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#rest_in_object_destructuring) to remove `isUpdated` and move all the remaining properties to a `rest` variable. I've added another snippet which uses `for` loop and does each step one at a time.

Comment: Okey, so, if I want to add the initialPosition attribute, is better to use the `for loop`?

Comment: I have resolved. I read the link of destructing and I have understood the code. Thanks.